# pg_connect crashes my php script

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to run a PHP script which has pg_connect($connection_string) and it just crashes my PHP script. I'm running it off of xampp on my computer, here are some facts:

- If I put exit("test"); immediately above the pg_connect statement, it successfully displays the word "test" and terminates the script, so I know that my installation of xampp is working.
- Using phpinfo() I can see that the postgresql extension is indeed loaded.
- I can connect to the database server from pgadmin, so it's not a firewall issue or anything like that.
- If I remove this exit statement, the pg_connect statement just hangs. There is no warning displayed or logged, and it never even gets past the function call. I even have:

  $db_crm = pg_connect($connection_str);

  if (!$db_crm) die("connection failed");

And "connection failed" is never even displayed. My browser just shows "this page cannot be displayed",after timing out.

What in the world could be causing this?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and it is because I didn't have the php-pgsql package on my ubuntu machine. sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is guys:
I have no reason why, but adding sslmode=disable to the end of my connection string made it work. What reason would it have to crash? I am on a windows machine and phpinfo() says OpenSSL is enabled..

Answer (score 1):

It's doubtful that the call is crashing PHP.  More likely is that for some reason, the call is hanging for some reason and PHP's max execution time is being exceeded.  [You can try extending the time limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) before making the pg_connect() call to see if it eventually comes back with something.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the Apache error logs
- Check the php error logs
- Make sure you have [logging enabled](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) in your Postgres config file.
- In your config, set

  ```
  log_min_error_statement (DEBUG5)
  ```

  to grab everything possible.
- Check the postgres error logs

Answer (score 0):

This sounds really stupid, but is your server running under SSL? I've had problems where a server will try to authenticate to ssl and hang indefinitely, trying to connect to a non-existent port.

Comment: I'm assuming it is. The original code did not have that property set in the connection flag. However, the original code is running on linux while when this problem occurred I was under windows.

Answer (score 0):

sslmode=disable did the trick for me. To disable ssl in postgres-config ( ssl = false  ) also worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the Apache logs revealed that PHP was not finding the pg_connect() function, even though php-postgresql was installed. Restarting Apache fixed this, i.e.

```
sudo service httpd restart
```